# Finding the general solution to a fourth order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

The given equation is 
$$y^{(4)}+5y^{''}+4y= \sin(x)+\cos(2x)$$
Using the auxiliary equation to find the roots result with $m_{1,2}=\pm i$ and $m_{3,4}=\pm 2i$. Usually the equation characteristic is $y= C_1e^{M_1}+C_2e^{M_2}$, but because we have imaginary terms we change the positive $i$ values into $\cos(x)$ and negatives into $\sin(x)$.

Meaning the characteristic function should look like

$$y_c=C_1\sin(x)+C_2 \cos(x)+C_3 \sin(2x)+C_4\cos(2x)$$
And knowing that $g(x)= \sin(x)+\cos(2x)$ we can see that there are duplicate within the two functions. So we must multiply $g(x)$ by $x$ in order to solve.
After multiplying out the $x$ our $y_p$ becomes
$$y_p=Ax\sin(x) +Bx \cos(x)+Cx\sin(2x)+dx\cos(2x)$$
Now taking the fourth derivative gives us $$
y^{(4)}_p=Ax\sin(x)-4A\cos(x)+Bx\cos(x)+4B\sin(x)+16Cx\sin(2x) -20C\cos(2x)+16Dx\cos(2x)+20D\sin(2x)$$
Now I plugged in each derivative into the given equation. After distributing and factoring my final answer is $$-6(A\cos(x)+B\sin(x))=\sin(x)+\cos(2x)$$
How can I find the general solution from here?

My work is below if you want to check my arithmetic.
[image]!

Comment: Recheck the solutions of the characteristic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y^{(4)}-5y^{''}+4y= \sin(x)+\cos(2x)$$
The characteristic polynomial is:
$$r^4-5r^2+4=0$$
$$r^2(r^2-4)-(r^2-4)=0$$
$$(r^2-4)(r^2-1)=0$$
$$(r-2)(r+2)(r-1)(r+1)=0$$
$$\implies S_r=\{-1,1,2,-2\}$$
The complementary solution is
$$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+c_3e^{2x}+c_4e^{-2x}$$
The particular solution should be of the form :
$$y_p=A\sin x + B \cos(2x)$$

Comment: Now is that before or after you altered it to account for duplicates in the $g(x)$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean Eric @EricBrown Are you talking about the particular solution ?

Comment: My professor said that the $y_p= Ax\sin(x)+Bx\cos(x)+Cx\sin(2x)+Dx\cos(2x)$ with the values of $m$ that I provided. The reason we multiply the characteristic solution by x is to bring all terms that are shared with  $g(x) to a higher degree in order not to have duplicates.

Comment: Well the homogeneous solution has no $\sin $ or $\cos$ function in it. So you don't have to apply that rule @EricBrown

Comment: The complementary solution has only exponetials  no sine nor cosine functions @EricBrown

Comment: From the given equation at the very top, on the RHS , that is our $g(x)$. It contains trig terms that are shared with the characteristic equation due to the values of $m$ (or $r$) being $i$ terms. Usually the equation characteristic is $y= C_1e^{M_1}+C_2e^{M_2}$, but because we have imaginary terms we change the positive $i$ values into $\cos(x)$ and negatives into $\sin(x)$.

Comment: No complex values in the characteristic polynomial. Only real values. Your calculation is not correct @EricBrown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106200/discussion-between-eric-brown-and-lostinspace).

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Start by noticing that

\begin{align*}
y'''' - 5y'' + 4y = \sin(x) + \cos(2x) & \Longleftrightarrow (y'' - 4y)'' - (y'' - 4y) = \sin(x) + \cos(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z'' - z = \sin(x) + \cos(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z' - z)' + (z' - z) = \sin(x) + \cos(2x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow w' + w = \sin(x) + \cos(2x)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?